# NSIS Issue. !include: could not find: "FontInstall.nsh"

Tags: fonts, nsis

I am creating an NSIS file to install software on a client machine as well as install fonts. Here is the where the problem lies.

```
;Include Modern UI

  !include "MUI2.nsh"
  RequestExecutionLevel Admin
  !include "FontInstall.nsh"
```

The last line will not go through as I get "could not find fontinstall.nsh; from nsis. Is this a plugin that I need to include? If so where do I find it. Am I right to assume that installing fonts on a client machine is not possible with NSIS so therefore there is no solution?

Comment: Yes, you can grab it at https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Installing_fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you got that code from probably linked to where you can download the .nsh because it is not part of standard NSIS.

You can find FontInstall.nsh [here](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Installing_fonts) and you also need to download the FontInfo plug-in from [here](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/FontInfo_plug-in) if you don't want to hardcode the internal font name in your script.